# opengl books and 3d math reference

Tags: opengl

Could anyone recommend some beginner opengl books from a shader approach?  Also, looking for some good 3d math references.

Comment: There are plenty of questions like this already on this site. Alternatively, go to the [OpenGL Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides).

Comment: Thanks, I am aware there are plenty of questions, however many of them go around in circles.  It's rough finding shader examples over the pipeline.  Many of the examples that use shaders are quite advanced, and assume you already know how to code in opengl.  No reason to downrate my post, I still think it's quite a valid question, even if it is reiterated.

Comment: That's not how SO works. We don't allow the same question to be repeated over and over just because you don't like the answers they get. We have a bounty system in place if you want to draw attention to a question.

Comment: Understand that, but it's quite rude to outright downrate a pretty valid question considering solid answers haven't been given.  Now, your link has provided me with good information, but the downrate on my relatively small amount of reputation definitely hurts.  Plus, my question was even uprated, then downrated twice within 30 minutes, kind of mean, don't you think?

Comment: Wow, I made myself look like sort of a tool, oh well. Starting a vote to delete the post, didn't fully understand SO at this point in my SO life =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these:

- [OpenGL Shading Language Ver. 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321637631)
- [OpenGL Programming Guide, 8th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321773039)
- [OpenGL SuperBible, 5th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321712617)
- [Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics, 3rd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1435458869)

There are surely more, but these ~3000 pages should give you a lot to think about.